# How to add multiple where clauses in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query

```
db.v_Report_CompanySearches
    .Select(x => x.PersonName)  //Only return Names
    .Distinct()     // Make to Unique
    .Where(y => y.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName))  //where 
    .OrderBy(x => x);
```

I only want it to return 1 column called PersonName, but I want to change the where clause to

```
PersonName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName) || AccountName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName)
```

AccountName is another column in there, but I can't get the syntax right. Does anyone know how to change it?

Thanks

Comment: Think on what is done **secuentially** to the data. You extract a IQueryable of strings (person names) and do a lookup on that one only field. If you had done the lookup (`.Where()`) prior the data extraction (`.Select()`), you could have filtered with every propery of the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the Where clause before the Select

```
db.v_Report_CompanySearches
.Where(y => y.PersonName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName) || y.AccountName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName) )  //where 
.Select(x => x.PersonName)  //Only return Names
.Distinct()     // Make to Unique
.OrderBy(z => z);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move `Select` after `Where`:

```
db.v_Report_CompanySearches
.Where(y => y.PersonName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName) 
            || y.AccountName.ToLower().Contains(mPersonName))  //where 
.Select(x => x.PersonName)  //Only return Names
.Distinct()     // Make to Unique
.OrderBy(x => x);
```